# Creating a Python VM but my program ends in a IndexError exception

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Python VM but for some reason I am getting errors when attempting to run my program.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

OP_EOP = "00"
OP_EOI = "01"
OP_PUSH = "02"
OP_POP = "03"
OP_PRINT = "04"
OP_ADD = "05"
OP_SUB = "06"

def load_program(argv):
    f = open(argv)
    lines = f.read().replace("\n", " ")
    lines = lines.split(" ")
    f.close()
    return lines

def DO_EOI():
    print "EOI"

def DO_PUSH():
    print "PUSH"

def DO_POP():
    print "POP"

def DO_PRINT():
    print "PRINT"

def DO_ADD():
    print "ADD"

def DO_SUB():
    print "SUB"

def execute_program(l):
    loop = 1
    i = 0
    while loop:
        instruction = l[i]
        if instruction == OP_EOP:
            loop = 0
            print "EOP"
        elif instruction == OP_EOI:
            DO_EOI()
        elif instruction == OP_PUSH:
            DO_PUSH()
        elif instruction == OP_POP:
            DO_POP()
        elif instruction == OP_PRINT:
            DO_PRINT()
        elif instruction == OP_ADD:
            DO_ADD()
        elif instruction == OP_SUB:
            DO_SUB()
        i += 1

def run_program(argv):
    l = load_program(argv)
    execute_program(l)

def main(argv):
    run_program(argv[1])
    return 0

def target(*args):
    return main, None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

When I run my program with Aafile called `hello.vm` that has this:

```
02 000A 01 04
```

(the `000A` should be ignored), I get this output (and errors)

```
PUSH
EOI
PRINT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm.py", line 70, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "vm.py", line 63, in main
    run_program(argv[1])
  File "vm.py", line 60, in run_program
    execute_program(l)
  File "vm.py", line 40, in execute_program
    instruction = l[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My desired output is this:

```
PUSH
EOI
PRINT
EOP
```

Comment: So what program did you feed this? Clearly, your code ends up with a list `l` that doesn't have more than 3 elements.

Comment: A file called hello.vm that has this: `02 000A 01 04` The `000A` should be ignored

Comment: So where is the `00` opcode that you expected to be printed? Without `00`, the loop on to increment `i`, and you try to access `l[4]`, which does not exist.

Comment: See, that input file is *crucial* to understanding what goes wrong here. The program is fine, your input is not. Now that we have the input, you have a [MCVE] and we can start answering this.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not include a `00` `EOP` instruction. Your *code* **expects** that instruction.

Your `execute_program()` function expects to execute the program in an infinite loop; it starts at instruction `0` (in the `i` variable), and will forever increment `i` until the `EOP` instruction, at which point `loop` is set to `0` and the `while loop:` test stops being true.

So *without* a `EOP`, you run out of instructions and you get your exception, because `loop = 0` is never executed.

You can remove the need for a mandatory `EOP` instruction by *also* testing if your have more instructions:

```
while loop and i < len(l):
```